# form input disabled works differently between chrome and firefox

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, firefox, google-chrome

I currently have a form with a disabled submit input.  In firefox 4.0, if you press enter nothing happens (which is what I want).

In Chrome (11) or IE 7, it will try to submit the page.

Is there some Jquery that will make Chrome & IE behave like Firefox in this example?

I've created a test page for people - http://jsfiddle.net/tEsEU/1/

Here is the output html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-CA">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="title">
                <h1>My App</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="logindisplay">
            </div>
            <div id="menucontainer">
                <ul id="menu">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <div>
<form action="/Home/ChangePeoPerm" method="post">    
    <label for="userName" class="visibleFalse">asdfsdf</label>
    <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" value="d" />
    <input type="submit" name="btnAddUser" id="btnAddUser" value=">>" disabled="disabled" />
</form></div>


            <div id="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my mvc View

```
<div>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("ChangePeoPerm", "Home"))
                {
                    <label for="userName" class="visibleFalse">asdfsdf</label>
                    <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" value="d" />
                    <input type="submit" name="btnAddUser" id="btnAddUser" value=">>" disabled="disabled" />
                }
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug in Chrome. The proposed solution is to use javascript to subscribe to the `onsubmit` event of the form and if the button is disabled cancel the submission. Here's how you could achieve this with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        return !$(':submit', this).is(':disabled');
    });
});
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the bug you listed is preventing forms from ever getting submitted. The question here is why is a form still submitting when the button is disabled.

Comment: @Jeremy B., that's correct. I've linked to a wrong article. Still that looks like a bug to me.

Comment: I chose this one as the answer because the answer is a bit more portable for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically block the submit event using jQuery:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    return $("#btnAddUser").attr("disabled") != "disabled";
});
```